# SELinux denials after migrating application data between devices

Tags: data-transfer, selinux, device-migration

I'm trying to migrate application data between devices. The application was installed to the work profile using Shelter The steps I did were:

1. On source phone, `tar cvf appdata.tar.gz /data/user/10/com.appname`
2. Copy the tarball from the source phone to the target phone
3. On the target phone, install the applications to the work profile. Note the username of the `/data/user/10/com.appname` on the target phone, which is of the form `u10_aXXX`
4. On the target phone, `chown -R u10_aXXX:u10_aXXX /data/user/10/com.appname`

When I'm trying to use the app, it receives a lot of SELinux AVC denials and ends up crashing because it's unable to open `/data/user/10/com.appname/databases/database.db`:

```
10-18 16:23:28.485  4120  4120 W SharedPreferenc: type=1400 audit(0.0:889): avc: denied { search } for name="shared_prefs" dev="dm-0" ino=860652 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c522,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

What am I missing? Application works after setting SELinux to permissive.

Comment: Run `restorecon -R /data/user/10/com.appname`.

Comment: worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

On newer Android versions the process mentioned in the question and comment is not sufficient. In my experience on LineageOS 20 (that is Android 13), the following changes were needed:

1. The `cache` and `code_cache` directories must be owned by `uX_aYYY_cache`
2. `restorecon` requires the `-D` parameter to touch files in /data/data

So the full process would be as follows:

1. Unpack the files to /data/*somewhere*/com.appname. *somewhere* depends on the system profile, the default is simply /data/data
2. `chown -R uX_aYYY:uX_aYYY com.appname`
3. `chown -R uX_aYYY:uX_aYYY_cache com.appname/cache`
4. `chown -R uX_aYYY:uX_aYYY_cache com.appname/code_cache`
5. `restorecon -DR com.appname`

Comment: You missed `uX_aYYY_cache` in steps 2,3. Would it be enough to just delete the cache dirs?

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected it now. I haven't tried deleting the directories, but my guess would be that something would break. They are created during app installation and survive the "remove app data" operation, so it would be reasonable to assume that they exist all the time and won't be created on-demand.