# How to fix a bootloop caused by accidental "fix contexts" from TWRP?

Tags: twrp, boot-loop, selinux, redmi

I am using TWRP recovery on my Redmi Note 10 Pro device for a long time, but recently while using TWRP recovery, I mistakenly clicked on 'fix contexts' option and now my phone is stuck in a bootloop.

I showed it to the nearest Xiaomi service center but they don't know how to fix the bootloop caused by the change in contexts. I don't have another phone and my phone is in bootloop for almost 8 days. I tried everything like installing stock Xiaomi ROM but nothing is working in this case.

Please tell me how I can get out of this problem.

Comment: your question is missing important detail: what do you want? I am pretty sure it's easy task for service center to flash stock ROM and **factory reset** device. but I get the feeling it's not what you're trying to ask for

Comment: make sure download correct ROM your device is [sweet](https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/sweet) or [chopin](https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/chopin). do not install eea/global ROM on china device

Comment: See [What does TWRP "Fix Contexts" do?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218409/218526) and [this comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248852#comment334684_248852).